# What is the deep physical reason behind the existence of bound entanglement?

Tags: entanglement, state-distillation, entanglement-negativity

In Quantum Information processing, we can extract entanglement from $n$-copies of a weakly entangled state to produce a fully or highly entangled states in $d$-dimensions, using the known distillation protocols.

However, there are states from which no entanglement can be extracted out using the known distillation protocols for no value of $n$. Such states contain bound entanglement.

For qubits, PPT is a necessary and sufficient criterion for separability. In higher dimensions, i.e qudits, there are states which satisfy PPT but are entangled and such states contain bound i.e non-distillable entanglement. I am not sure but I guess there are states which are NPT but bound entangled.

What is the deep physical reason behind the existence of bound entanglement?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Whether there is any deep physical reason for existence of bound entanglement or not

Comment: "deep physical reason" is a bit subjective. Can you be more specific?

Comment: *"I am not sure but I guess there are states which are NPT but bound entangled."* -- That's one of the big open questions in quantum information theory.